# Can not use jQuery selector to get attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering that why I can not use jQuery selector to get attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" class="inputText" value="Enter text...">
console.log($('.inputText').getAttrbute('value'));
```

The chrome dev tool shows me error message: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getAttrbut is not a function".

But the native JavaScript way is OK:

```
var input = document.body.children[0];
console.log(input.getAttribute('value')); //Enter text...
```

Comment: Even if jQuery had a function by that name, it would still lack an "i" and an "e". `getAttrbut` -> `getAttribute`

Comment: Not really. At least not properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use val() on a jQuery object or getAttribute on a JavaScript object.

```
console.log($('.inputText').val());
```

You can also get the JavaScript object from the jquery object by using [0] after the object.

```
console.log($('.inputText')[0].getAttrbut('value'));
```

To get just any attribute you can use attr(), but if you are looking for the input value use val()

Comment: Thanks. I think that I am confusing JavaScript object with jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery method is [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
console.log($('.inputText').attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `$('.inputText')` gives you jquery object not the direct dom element. Also dom element don't have property `getAttrbut()` instead its `getAttribute()`.

You can get it:

```
console.log($('.inputText').val());//recommended
console.log($('.inputText').attr('value'));
console.log($('.inputText').prop('value'));
console.log($('.inputText').get(0).getAttribute('value')); //use get() to access direct dom element.
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery does not have any method called "getAttrbute". but if you need to access attribute then use "attr" like this

```
$(".inputT").attr("AttributeName");
```

Or if you want to remove attribute then use

```
$(".inputT").removeAttr("AttributeName");
```